# Why $\frac{|w-z|}{|1-\overline{w}z|} < 1$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Question:**
Why $\frac{|w-z|}{|1-\overline{w}z|} <1 $ for $w$ and $z$ in $D(0,1)=\{c \in \mathbb{C}: |c|<1 \}$?

**Attempt:**
I know that this is quite trivial but I cannot compute it. I tried multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by $w$. The I got $\frac{|w-z|}{|w-|w|^2z|}$ but I do not know how to continue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked and answered frequently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/506058 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%7Cw-z%7C%7D%7B%7C1-%5Coverline%7Bw%7Dz%7C%7D%20%3C1%24)